# I want to implement the same scrolling behavior as tesla website uses

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When you scroll down the tesla website, they have sections that are full height of the screen, and when you scroll it, the sections kind of snap to be the full height of the window. Any idea how can I do the same behavior?
https://www.tesla.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What stops you from studying the source code of that site?

Comment: Investigate IntersectionObserver so when a section comes opinto view you scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good reference about scroll snap on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap

for full screen sizes you can use viewport relative units (vh , vw)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.